# Were there conflicts between Gods before the Itihasas and Puranas?

Tags: puranas, gods, itihasa

In the Rig Veda the conflicts are mostly between Gods and anti-Gods like Vritra.  But the Rig Veda does hint at conflict between Indra and Vishnu.

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/r06.html?lang=sa

> उ॒भा जि॑ग्यथु॒र्न परा॑ जयेथे॒ न परा॑ जिग्ये कत॒रश्च॒नैनोः॑ ।
>   इन्द्र॑श्च विष्णो॒ यदप॑स्पृधेथां त्रे॒धा स॒हस्रं॒ वि तदै॑रयेथाम् ॥ ६.०६९.०८

6.69.8 (Brererton and Jamison translation)

> You both have conquered; you are not conquered. Neither one of these two has been conquered.O Viṣṇu and you Indra, when you two were contending, you broke apart the thousand in three parts.

But head-on conflicts between Gods seem to be recorded only in the Itihasas and Puranas.

Comment: Can you provide references to your statement - Rig Veda hints at conflict between Indra and Vishnu.??

Comment: Does not seem that they were "contending" with each other . Here is another translation https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Rig_Veda/Mandala_6/Hymn_69

Answer (score 1):

The translation provided by OP may not be correct.

Rig Veda [6.69.8](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv06069.htm)

> ubhā jighyathurna parā jayethe na parā jighye kataraścanainoḥ |
> indraśca viṣṇo yadapaspṛdhethāṃ tredhā sahasraṃ vi tadairayethām ||

The translation of H.H. Wilson ([p.113](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/rigveda/shakala-samhita-2/rigveda-shakala-samhita-mandal-06-sukta-069/)) is as follows:

> You have both ever been victorious; never have been conquered; neither
> of you has been vanquished; ***with whomsoever you have contended***, you
> have thrice conquered thrice.

---

The mantra says, both Indra and Vishnu remained unconquered.

---

Coming to conflicts between Gods mentioned in Puranas, it is better to talk less about that aspect.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question @srimannarayana k v .

Comment: It answers.  Your question is about conflicts between Gods that were mentioned in Rig Veda. When such conflicts were not mentioned, especially between Indra and Vishnu, the answer will be NO only